# EmberJS Formatting hasMany relation

Tags: ember.js

I have the following model setup:

`deliveryMethods: DS.hasMany("delivery-method", { async: true })`

With this computed property:

```
  ### COMPUTED PROPERTIES ###
  formattedDeliveryOptions: (->
    @get('deliveryMethods').map((dm) ->
      console.log dm.toJSON()
      return { key: dm.get('name').underscore, value: dm.get('name') }
    )
  ).property("deliveryMethods.@each")
```

And I am trying to access this property in a controller like so:

```
  deliveryMethodsArray: (->
    org = @get('controllers.application.currentOrganization')
    console.log org.get('formattedDeliveryOptions')
    return org.get('formattedDeliveryOptions')
  ).property()
```

But when the `console.log dm.toJSON()` runs, the `organization` property is set but nothing else. Not sure what I am doing wrong

`console.log` output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because the async is true, i believe you need to do a then() on the get promise.

```
org.get('formattedDeliveryOptions').then((fmtOpts) => { /* do something*/ });
```

Please excuse my syntax, you use a slightly different shorthand version than i do. The concept should be the same though.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, this app was developed in CoffeeScript (blugh).. But I tried that and it didn't work :/ Keep getting this error: `org.get('formattedDeliveryOptions').then is not a function(…)`

Comment: Is `formattedDeliveryOptions` actually returning anything? I see that the map function is returning, but not the actual computedProperty

Comment: I updated the answer to include what I see in the `console.log`